# Using margins correctly on width with percentage %

Tags: html, css

I wish to have some centered content with 2 side panels. Do I need to switch to % values instead of pixels for the margin values?

Obviously I want them to fit fully in the page and prevent the blocks moving down on resize. I plan to use @media queries down the line.
HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="box1">Box 1</div>
    <div class="box2">Box 2</div>
    <div class="box3">Box 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.box1 {
    width:23%;
    margin:5px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    float:left;
    height:500px;
}
div.box2 {
    width:50%;
    margin:5px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    float:left;
    height:500px;
}
div.box3 {
    width:23%;
    margin:5px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    float:left;
    height:500px;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vjxv8mwa/)

Comment: try :  `margin:5px auto;`

Answer (score 1):

To prevent it from moving down, you can use `flexbox`

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/esLm2gmm/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box1">Box 1</div>
    <div class="box2">Box 2</div>
    <div class="box3">Box 3</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container
{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:nowrap;
}

div.box1 {
    width:23%;
    margin:5px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    float:left;
    height:500px;
}
div.box2 {
    width:50%;
    margin:5px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    float:left;
    height:500px;
}
div.box3 {
    width:23%;
    margin:5px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    float:left;
    height:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `%` for width and `px` for padding, margin and borders.
But you will have to take those in account while setting your width. The easiest way is with calc.

Here is an example for your div 1. You want it to take 23% with a left margin of 5px, a right margin of 5px, a left border of 3px and a right border of 3px. Margin and border take 16px wide. So your width can be `calc(50% - 16px);`

Below is your complete CSS using `calc`

```
div.box1 {
    width:calc(23% - 16px);
    margin:5px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    float:left;
    height:500px;
} 

div.box2 {
    width:calc(50% - 16px);
    margin:5px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    float:left;
    height:500px;
} 
div.box3 {
    width:calc(23% - 16px);
    margin:5px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    float:left;
    height:500px;
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vjxv8mwa/2/) is your updated fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you can using display:table and display:table-cell to have a cool column layout

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="box1">Box 1</div>
    <div class="box2">Box 2</div>
    <div class="box3">Box 3</div>
</div>



.main {
   display:table;
   table-layout:fixed;   
   width:100%;
}
.box1, .box2, .box3 {
    display:table-cell;
}
div.box1 {
    width:23%;
    padding:5px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
div.box2 {
    width:50%;
    padding:5px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
div.box3 {
    width:23%;
    padding:5px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

You can also used display:flex but you it's not compatible with IE9

Comment: I always thought tables were frowned upon in HTML5 for layout nowadays?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, percentage is a great way. Bootstrap framework is even better. 
Here's the solution: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vjxv8mwa/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box2">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box3">Box 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{
    display:inline-block; 
    width: 100%; 
    float: left; 
}

.box1 {
    width:20%;
    margin:5px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    float:left;
    height:500px;
} 

.box2 {
    width:50%;
    margin:5px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    float:left;
    height:500px;
} 
.box3 {
    width:20%;
    margin:5px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    float:left;
    height:500px;
}
```

The percentage had to be even lower for your side-content because the margin accounts for some of that space.

Answer (score -1):

No you don't have to.

If you want to center an element in both ways (vertical and horizontal) you can do it by using only CSS:

```
position: absolute;
display: block;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
width: 200px;
height: 300px;
margin-left: -100px;
margin-top: -150px;
```

this will center the div it's applied to. Why? because you can use negative values on margins which will move the div into the other direction starting from the 0x0 pixels position rather than the corners of the document. Combining this with "left: 50%" and "top: 50%" and using the half of the width in negative for margin-left and the half of the height in negative for margin-top will place the center of the element to left: 50% and top: 50% which is, obviously, the center of the page.

for the element on the left, you have to use the half of the width of the left div plus the width of the centerd div for margin-left in negative way, and for the element on the right you have to use the half of the width of the right div in negative way plus the width of the centered div for margin-left in positive way.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            div#left{
                position: absolute;
                display: block;
                left: 50%;
                top: 50%;
                width: 200px;
                height: 300px;
                margin-left: -300px;
                margin-top: -150px;
                background-color: green;
            }
            div#centered{
                position: absolute;
                display: block;
                left: 50%;
                top: 50%;
                width: 200px;
                height: 300px;
                margin-left: -100px;
                margin-top: -150px;
                background-color: red;
            }
            div#right{
                position: absolute;
                display: block;
                left: 50%;
                top: 50%;
                width: 200px;
                height: 300px;
                margin-left: 100px;
                margin-top: -150px;
                background-color: blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="left"></div>
        <div id="centered"></div>
        <div id="right"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```